# Reorder columns of matrix, with each row taking on a different order

Tags: r, permutation

I think the question is self explanatory, but to be clear:

I essentially want to permute the elements of a matrix in an efficient way, **not** simply reorder columns such that the relationship between the columns remains the same.

Right now, I'm trying to produce this reordering as such:

```
inds=matrix(nrow=nrow(datExprNorm),ncol=ncol(datExprNorm))
for(i in 1:nrow(datExprNorm)){
  inds[i,]=sample(1:ncol(datExprNorm),ncol(datExprNorm))
}
```

And then index my original matrix with the reordered entries:

```
datPermut=datExprNorm[inds]
```

But I run into this error:

> Error in datExprNorm[inds] :    such indexing must be by logical
> or 2-column numeric matrix

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think your question is not as clear as you think, e.g. what you are doing is NOT permuting through your matrix (which is getting all possible combination of rows and/or columns), instead you are simply drawing random samples from your matrix. So please clarify if you want to draw random sample or really permute through your matrix. Please also clarify if just want to draw random sample of rows or if you really want to replace values of a row by random column values.

Comment: I would like to draw random samples (without replacement), replacing values in a row with random column values. I will edit the question so as not to use the term "permute".

Comment: Okay, apologies then, I misunderstood your question. Yes, I want to sample values from the NUMBER of columns, thus reordering columns. I realize in the question I write rows, I will adjust this as well. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to get it running by doing a round trip through converting to numerics first and then re-creating a matrix:

```
datExprNorm_numeric <- as.numeric(datExprNorm)
inds_numeric <- as.numeric(inds)

sampled <- datExprNorm_numeric[inds_numeric]

datPermut <- matrix(sampled, nrow = nrow(datExprNorm), ncol = ncol(datExprNorm))
```

---

Here's a smaller toy example:

```
x <- matrix(c(4, 3, 2, 1), nrow = 2)
```

gives:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    4    2
[2,]    3    1
```

and

```
y <- matrix(c(1, 1, 2, 2), nrow = 2)
```

gives

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    1    2
```

now combine:

```
z <- as.numeric(x)[as.numeric(y)]

z <- matrix(z, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
```

result:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    4    3
[2,]    4    3
```